# azure function v 2.0 and key vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-functions-runtime

My azure function written using Function runtime Version 2.0 and trying to read secrets from azure key vault.

```
public class KeyVaultAccess
{

    private const string VaulturL = "...";
    private const string ClientId = "...";
    private const string thumbprinT = "...";

    public static string GetSecretIdentifier(string secretName)
    {
        string nextLink = VaulturL + "secrets" + "/" + secretName;
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
        var getsecrets = Task.Run(async () => await keyVaultClient.GetSecretsAsync(VaulturL));
        Task.WaitAll(getsecrets);

        if (getsecrets.Result == null)
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving secret name from key vault");
        var secret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(nextLink).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var GetSecretvalue = secret.Value;
        return GetSecretvalue;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var clientcred = new ClientCredential(ClientId, thumbprinT);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientcred);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

I have referenced below nuget packages in the function. 
[image: Nuget Packages]

when i run the function using VS local CLI and the function not running and getting the error. 
[image: CLI Error]

FYI, the same code is working fine in Azure Function V1.0.

Any clue what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the reference of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`.

It has been fixed in latest function runtime `2.0.11857`(aka cli `2.0.1-beta.29`). See [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1715) and [pull request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/1724).

Release is complete on portal, but as the [release note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11857-alpha) says

> This release has not yet been made available to Visual Studio users.

So you can download [cli beta.29](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/2.0.1-beta.29) manually (win-x64 or x86, based on your platform) and configure following debug settings.

```
Launch: Executable
Executable: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (set your dotnet path)
Application Arguments: [yourclifolderpath]\Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64\func.dll start
Working Directory: $(TargetDir)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, It's working fine now.. Thanks a ton :-).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12115.0

Comment: @Jan-TerjeSørensen Can't repro it with latest runtime, check this [nuget reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need) to see whether your dependencies are latest. If still baffled, you could open a new issue with your code.

Comment: @JerryLiu - The solution to my issue was to reenter my credentials: Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication -> Reenter your credentials

Comment: @Jan-TerjeSørensen Thanks for offering your solution, looks like an [authentication problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-visual-studio).